# Deploying same Azure cloud function for each environment - dev, qa, prod

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-cloud-services

Have a function app with single cloud function in it. The cloud function is triggered by an HTTP call and pushes the payload to a Azure service bus queue. What needs to be done is, as part of automated deployment, would like to have few variables configured per environment -

1. Function Name
2. Queue Name
3. Queue Connection String

Deployment is to be done using Azure DevOps. Function code is also on Azure DevOps repository which will have branch for each environment, so will need function with different function name for eg - Dev_Function, QA_Function,etc since it needs to connect to corresponding environment queue. Also aware that variables can be configured using App Settings on Azure portal. Any help/insights appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i think you could keep the function name as it is and change make the **Queue name** and **Connection string** to be pickup from **Azure function app service configuration**.

```
 [FunctionName("SendEmailFunc")]
    public static async Task SendEmailFunc([QueueTrigger($"%{FuncAppConstants.Queue.EmailQueueName}%")] EmailMessage emailMessage)
    {
}
```

you can get the queue name at runtime by using this

```
[QueueTrigger($"%prod_queue_name%")]
```

and configuration will just look like below in the local.setting.json

```
 "prod_queue_name": "test-email-queue"
```

and similarly in the Azure function app configuration

[image]

And same can be done for the `connection string`

Comment: Thanks @thanzeel. The difference here being my function is HTTP triggered, not queue. However, it publishes message to the queue using ServiceBus attribute like this - [return: ServiceBus("queue-name", Connection = "ConnectionStringAppSetting")]. It doesn't allow to replace the "queue-name" with any App setting variable!!!1

Comment: you can hard code the variable name

Comment: The need is to inject the variables when the function is deployed using Azure devops pipeline, hence trying to make it dynamic rather than a const string

Comment: I can name the variable which will be pickup at runtime, its not a constant name of the queue. In the name of the varibale that you need to hardcode